# How to send data with curl request

Tags: c++, visual-c++, curl

I'm writing code for sending http request with data. But I can't send data at particular URL. I am using curl for http request. I can get whole output of curl but so far unable to send data with it. When I send request, it should go with some data like hello. How can I do this?

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <stdio.h>
#include "curl/curl.h"
#include "curl\easy.h"


int main(void)
{
  CURL *curl;
  CURLcode res;

  /* In windows, this will init the winsock stuff */ 
  curl_global_init(CURL_GLOBAL_ALL);

  curl = curl_easy_init();
  if(curl) {
    /* First set the URL that is about to receive our POST. This URL can
       just as well be a https:// URL if that is what should receive the
       data. */ 
  curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, "http://localhost:8080/Main/GiveResponse.jsp");
    /* Now specify the POST data */ 

 curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, "prod1");





    /* Perform the request, res will get the return code */ 
    res = curl_easy_perform(curl);
    /* Check for errors */ 
    if(res != CURLE_OK)
      fprintf(stderr, "curl_easy_perform() failed: %s\n",
              curl_easy_strerror(res));

    /* always cleanup */ 
    curl_easy_cleanup(curl);
  }
  curl_global_cleanup();

 system ("pause");
  return 0;

}
```

Comment: This program sends data already. You need to specify better what's wrong with it...

Answer (score 1):

Its working..check ur localhost connection or check GiveResponse.JSP is working fine without any error.

Comment: pod1 is one parameter in GiveResponse.jsp so now i have to pass like curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, "prod1=MyName");

Its working succesfully now..thank you.